# Normalising using Unipath in a wsgi environment doesnt' produce a normalised answer

Tags: python, django, python-3.4

I am debugging a Django app that runs quite happily as `python manage.py runserver ...` but does not when run under uWSGI with Python 3.4.  What I have discovered is that my Unipath selector works fine in the manage.py environment but produces the wrong result when run under the uWSGI.  These leads to all sorts of difficulties and odd messages.

So the debugging code in my settings file is:

> `print("Hi from settings/base.py file = {}, cleaned up ={}".format(__file__,str(Path(__file__))))`

Under manage.py I get:

> `Hi from settings/base.py file = /home/ubuntu/projects/myproj/myproj/myproj/settings/base.py, cleaned up = /home/ubuntu/projects/myproj/myproj/myproj/settings/base.py`

and run using uwsgi I get:

> `Hi from settings/base.py file = ./myproj/settings/base.py, cleaned up = ./myproj/settings/base.py`

I was expecting the URL to be normalised.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `absolute()` first, like this:

```
print('Hi from settings/base.py file = {}, cleaned up  {}'.format(
    __file__,
    str(Path(__file__).absolute()),
))
```